# Change font in all tables of the document

Tags: tables, fonts

I would like to change the default font in all tables of my document. Instead of the Computer Modern Roman font I prefer Bitstream Charter Mathdesign (the same family), which is "condensed":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter, uppercase=upright]{mathdesign}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmr}

\g@addto@macro{\table}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{mdbch}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{My Table}\label{tab:table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
      X & Y \\ \hline
      x1 & y1 \\
      x2 & y2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Some short text outside a table in a current font.

\end{document}
```

Using the following code, the Mathdesign font is used for the entire document :-(

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Isn't the `mathdesign` package doing this change already for the whole document?

Comment: @Christian: I am not sure... For me works only for formulas or for the entire document. The problem is that there is a large lyx document with hundred of tables, math formulas and a current text. The math is based on Libertine new TX font. I would like to change only font in all tables without changing the math font.

Answer (score 4):

Probably solved in a different way, using the environment command and a different nick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}
     {\renewcommand\familydefault{mdbch}
      \@float{table}}
     {\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{My Table}\label{tab:table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
      X & Y \\ \hline
      x1 & y1 \\
      x2 & y2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Some short text outside a table in a current font.

\end{document}
```

Maybe, it helps....